# After changing the common settings of permalinks to "post name", Now my navigation menu is not working

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have installed the wordpress and then create some pages with the default permalinks settings.
These pages are displaying in the navigation menu.
Now when I changed the permalinks common settings to the "post name" instead of the default, Now all the links on the site is working but the pages in the navigation menu are not working. The redirects me to the page not found error message.

What can I do for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your navigation menu might be hardcoded in your theme's header.php file, so when you changed the permalink structure, the old links are now pointing to nonexistent pages.

Comment: No, The navigation menu is not hard coded. When I create a page, It automatically display in the navigation menu.

Comment: What kind of server are you on? If it's Windows, that can make things a little tricky. Also, can you post a link to the live site, since it's hard to troubleshoot blindly.